# Spinner(UIActivityIndicator) doesn't show in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I want to show spinner while downloading files from the url. It downloads the file but doesn't show spinner. And label is also not coming in center.
How can i make it to center.

I have already tried using self.view.center, but doesn't work.

Code

```
container = [[UIView alloc] init];
//container.center = self.view.center;
activityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

activityLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(message, @"string1");
activityLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
activityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8];
[container addSubview:activityLabel];
activityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30, 55, 225, 50);

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[container addSubview:activityIndicator];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(30, 55, 225, 50);
[self.view addSubview:container];
container.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width/2, container.frame.size.height/2);
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Please put some light on it....

Comment: Is that your viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
-(void)startAnimating{
UIView *  container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
container.center = self.view.center;
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.4];
container.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
container.layer.masksToBounds = true;
container.tag = 134;
UILabel * activityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
activityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, 100, 30);
activityLabel.text = @"Description";
activityLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
activityLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
activityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
[container addSubview:activityLabel];


UIActivityIndicatorView *  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width/2, container.frame.size.height/2);
[container addSubview:activityIndicator];

[self.view addSubview:container];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

-(void)stopAnimating{
    UIView * containView = [self.view viewWithTag:134];
    [containView removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

When you want to start,call `[self startAnimating]`

When want to stop,just call `[self stopAnimating]`

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leo....it works...but how can i make it center....its not in center in neither iphone4s nor in iphone6.....

Comment: You have to set center of the `containView` to the to `self.view.center`

Comment: one more question...how can i hide container as well as label once downloading is finished....spinner is stopped... Can I change the color of spinner other than white/black/gray?

Comment: You want label in the center? Normally it should be the spinner in the center

Answer (score 1):

I call this method every time that i want to show an activity indicator.

```
 - (void) showActivityIndicator{

    self.spinner.hidden=NO;


    [self.spinner startAnimating];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.spinner];

    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];


    }
```

And here it is my viewDidLoad method

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

       self.spinner= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

       self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);

       [self.spinner setCenter:self.view.center]; // I do this because I'm in      landscape mode
       [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];

       self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

}
```

And thats how i call this function.

```
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showActivityIndicator) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set frame of your container. I guess you setted:

`activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(30, 55, 225, 50);`

instead of

`container.frame = CGRectMake(30, 55, 225, 50);`

And to put container in center do this:

```
container.center=self.view.center;
```

In your code you are putting container in center of itself.

Comment: call these two lines before [self.view addSubview:container];

container.center = self.view.center;
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(container.frame.size.width/2, container.frame.size.height/2);